# Value is not being passed to another page using AJAX?

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

I am passing a hidden input value to another page using AJAX and displaying there, 
 but value is not being passed. I am newbie to PHP, jQuery and AJAX. Can anyone help me out?

index.php:

```
<?php 
  foreach($imgs as $keys => $vals)
  {
    echo '<img class="myimg1" id="myimg" src="' . "images/$vals" . '" width="20%" height="20%"/>';
    echo '<input type="hidden" value="'.$vals.'" name="delete_file" id="delete_file" />';
    echo '<input type="button" value="Delete image" onclick="delete_image()"/>';
  }
?>
```

js

```
function delete_image() {
  var status = confirm("Are you sure you want to delete ?");  
  if (status == true) {
    var file = $("#delete_file").val();
    $.ajax({
      type: "POST",
      url: "action.php",
      data: { file: file },
      success(html) {
        alert('Deleted');
      }
    });
  }
}
```

action.php

```
<?php
  $num = $_POST["file"];
  echo $num;
?>
```

Comment: did you try a var_dump($_POST); ? something else try to name your parameter with different name of the JS variable like : data:{file_php:file},

Comment: You have a syntax error in the jQuery. `success` is a property which accepts a function. Change the syntax of that line to `success: function(html) {`. I would strongly suggest you check the console for other errors

Comment: i was already tried changing variable names function name,onclick function name etc @Inazo

Answer (score -1):

You are looping images and all of those images get the same name and ID. This cannot be good. I would change this so they all get a different name and ID.

```
<?php 
  $counter = 0;
  foreach($imgs as $keys => $vals)
  {
    echo '<img class="myimg1" id="myimg" src="' . "images/$vals" . '" width="20%" height="20%"/>';
    echo '<input type="hidden" value="'.$vals.'" name="delete_file[' . $counter . ']" id="delete_file_' . $counter . '" />';
    echo '<input type="button" value="Delete image" onclick="delete_image()"/>';
    $counter++;
  }
?>
```

You can also put the images in a form and serialize that with jQuery to send it through Ajax.

Also change the success part of the following to see PHP errors:

```
function delete_image() {
  var status = confirm("Are you sure you want to delete ?");  
  if (status == true) {
    var file = $("#delete_file").val();
    $.ajax({
      type: "POST",
      url: "action.php",
      data: { file: file },
      success: function(data, textStatus, jqXHR) {
        // use console.log to find PHP errors in the console of the browser
        console.log(data); 
        // you can alert data or use is to check for errors of whatever you want
        if (data == 'success') { alert(data); } 
      }
    });
  }
}
```

Comment: <!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<title>action</title>
</head>

<body>
 djffj600x250.png</body>
</html>

Comment: output of browser console but value is still not passed on action .php